# Embed openfire in a spring java application

Tags: java, spring, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

Is it possible to embed open fire or any xmpp server in a spring java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tigase, is a better option.

You can get to work form within java.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say that you want to embed openfire in your web application, that application can also contain Spring or any other framework.

You can embed Openfire in any web application, just set System property for openfireHome eg: 
`-DopenfireHome="C:\ChatServer\openfire"`.
Also you have to start the openfire from the application it self. i.e. openfire server should be working in standalone mode.
To start openfire server create 1 ServletContextListener, in that call                       `ServerStarter.main(null);`
This code will start the server in standalone mode.

Comment: thanks @Andro-selva  for editing the answer. I am new to this portal , so it will take some time to format answer correctly..:-)